# Can i detect my bot's groups with Telegram bot api

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Can i detect if my bot was added to group or get list groups where my bot included? Is it possible?
My version is forward message from group to my bot and get chat id from message, but I think it's not best solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bot get's `Update` with `new_chat_members` (Array of [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user))

As Telegram Bot API said `new_chat_members` is:

> New members that were added to the group or supergroup and information about them (the bot itself may be one of these members)

If you've got `Update` with your bot inside `new_chat_members`, just fetch chat_Id from `Update`

Comment: Hm. You are right. I thought that when bot was added to chat at first time it can't see self as new member. Thank you